# Swapping two rows in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I've created a ListView that in each row has a button with UP and DOWN arrow. Pressing these buttons makes the row to be shifted one position up or down.

I've achieved it by implementing OnClickListener for both buttons in a the override method getView. It works as it should however I fill bad with that cuz it seems to be highly memory consuming and lots of code is doubled.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBoxes.add(position, checkBox);

    String address = this.getItem(position).getAddress();
    String tokenizedAddress = tokenizeAddress(address);

    textView.setText(tokenizedAddress);

    ImageButton buttonUp = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_up);
    ImageButton buttonDown = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_down);

    buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListAdapter adapter = ListAdapter.this;

            if(position != 0 ){
                GameTask current = adapter.getItem(position);

                ArrayList<GameTask> list = new ArrayList<GameTask>();
                for( int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++ )
                    list.add(adapter.getItem(i));
                list.remove(position);
                list.add(position-1, current);
                adapter.clear();
                for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ){
                    adapter.add(list.get(i));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });

    buttonDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListAdapter adapter = ListAdapter.this;

            if(position != adapter.getCount()-1 ){
                GameTask current = adapter.getItem(position);

                ArrayList<GameTask> list = new ArrayList<GameTask>();
                for( int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++ )
                    list.add(adapter.getItem(i));
                list.remove(position);
                list.add(position+1, current);
                adapter.clear();
                for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ){
                    adapter.add(list.get(i));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });


    return rowView;
}
```

Both listeners do almost the same, the only difference is the condition and the value of shifting +1/-1. I was wondering about creating the inner class implementing OnClickListener in the extended ArrayAdapter class however, I have no idea, how I could then pass the position of the row clicked to this inner class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding and removing elements from your ArrayList, you can better implement [`Collections.swap(List list, int firstElementIndex, int secondElementIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29) it would be much easier as you don't have to iterate through the whole Collection. A simple example for the same can be found [`here`](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/collections/swap-list-elements-example).

Answer (score 1):

You could make a method that would be used by both `buttonUp` and `buttonDown`. This method could take as a parameter the type of action that was pressed (UP/DOWN), and the position of item in ListView, and then call this method in both of your click listener passing the appropriate action.

Example:

```
// 2 new constants
private static final int UP = 0;
private static final int DOWN = 1;

// Based on "type", increment or decrement the position.

private void changeRow(int type, int position){
        if(type==UP){
                position=position-1;
        }else if(type==DOWN){
                position=position+1;
        }

        // ........

        // Then in your "for" cicle you specify:
        list.add(position, current);

       // ........
}
```

Then in the onClick() method of `buttonUp` you specify:

```
changeRow(UP, position);
```

and for `buttonDown`:

```
changeRow(DOWN, position);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved

The way to do this is to store the data to be displayed in an `List`

Then when the user clicks the up or down arrow

Swap the references of data items which are shifting position using [`Collections.swap(List, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29)

Then call [`notifyDataSetChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the adapter

Comment: Ok, thanks to all answers here. They were really helpful. But tell me, is it possible to create single static listener that would be notified about the position of the row that was clicked? Instead of 2 listeners for each row. Or it isn't so memory and time consuming and I shouldn't bother?

Comment: I think you shouldn't bother but if you think it may be a bottleneck profile it to be sure .